# Load iFrame and print it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an ASPX page with hidden iframe.
I'm trying to: on button click load another page into that hidden iFrame and print it's content:

```
$("#shareButtonPrint").click(function () {
        $("#PrintFrame").attr('src', '/ProtocolPrintPage.aspx?g=1');
        $("#PrintFrame").ready(function () {
            window.frames['PrintFrame'].print();
        });

    });
```

but the code above doesn't work.

It works only when I load the iframe on main page load:

```
$("#PrintFrame").attr('src', '/ProtocolPrintPage.aspx?g=1');
    $("#shareButtonPrint").click(function () {
        //$("#PrintFrame").attr('src', '/ProtocolPrintPage.aspx?g=1');
        window.frames['PrintFrame'].print();
    });
```

**How can I load the iframe on button click ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to the iframe not yet being loaded when you're trying to print it

Perhaps try using `load` instead of `ready`

Check out my example here

http://jsfiddle.net/andyw_/umYkV/451/

Only tested in latest chrome + IE8-10.

Also note that `load` is deprecated

http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

The new way of doing it is `on('load', fn)`

Comment: Great answer, so what is the difference between 'ready' and 'load' events?

Comment: As per the documentation - ready only waits for the certain parts of the html to be parsed and DOM to be ready, but not necessarily rendered and along with external sources i.e. scripts, css, images etc. load on the other hand waits for everything to be loaded